# Rails 5 multiple joins showing same output data for both tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

This is my query:

```
@cities = City
            .left_outer_joins(:city_subs, :city_tags)
            .select(:name, 'cities.id, COUNT(city_subs.city_id) AS scount, COUNT(city_tags.city_id) AS pcount')
            .order(:name)
            .group(:name, 'cities.id')
```

The problem is that for both tables the value of count for each row is same, which is wrong! How many I fix this?
Also, will the solution you provide will be equally good for PostgreSQL?
TIA